# Is it possible to define a placeholder signal for a signal that hasn't yet been defined in ReactiveCocoa?

Tags: objective-c, reactive-programming, reactive-cocoa

As an example, say I have a `JSViewController` with a  `UIButton`. I'd like to expose a signal representing `[UIButton rac_signalForControlEvents:UIControlEventsTouchUpInside]` in the interface for `JSViewController`, but I'll be loading the `UIButton` in `-viewDidLoad:`.

This presents a problem: the `UIButton`'s signal isn't available until the `-viewDidLoad` is executed.

```
@interface JSViewController : UIViewController
@property (nonatomic, strong) RACSignal *buttonPressedSignal;
@end

@implementation JSViewController

- (instancetype)initWithNibName:(NSString *)nibNameOrNil bundle:(NSBundle *)nibBundleOrNil {
    // buttonPressedSignal needs to be defined here
}

- (void)viewDidLoad {
    UIButton *button = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeSystem];
    [self.view addSubview:button];
    self.buttonPressedSignal = [button rac_signalForControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
}

@end
```

Is there a way I can create a "placeholder" signal that forwards events from `[button rac_signalForControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside]` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Observe the view controller's `isViewLoaded` property, filter out `NO` values, and then `-flattenMap:` the `YES` value into a signal of the button's control events:

```
- (RACSignal *)buttonEvents
{
    @weakify(self);
    return [[[RACObserve(self, isViewLoaded)
            filter:^BOOL(NSNumber *isLoaded) {

                return isLoaded.boolValue;

            }]
            take:1]
            flattenMap:^id(id _) {

                @strongify(self);
                return [self.myButton rac_signalForControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];

            }];
}
```

Comment: The `-isViewLoaded` “property” isn't documented to be KVO-compliant (like most of UIKit), so I wouldn’t rely upon it.

Comment: I wasn't aware of that, thanks for calling it out. @jonsibley, using isViewLoaded worked for me, but if you wanted to be safe you could either create your own KVO-compliant property and set it in `-viewLoaded`.

Answer (score 3):

One solution is to create `RACSubject` as the placeholder signal, and make it subscribe `UIButton`'s signal once the signal is created:

```
@interface JSViewController : UIViewController
@property (nonatomic, strong) RACSubject *buttonPressedSubject;
@end

@implementation JSViewController

- (instancetype)initWithNibName:(NSString *)nibNameOrNil bundle:(NSBundle *)nibBundleOrNil {
    self = [super initWithNibName:nibNameOrNil bundle:nibBundleOrNil];
    if (self) {
        _buttonPressedSubject = [RACSubject subject];
    }

    return self;
}

- (void)viewDidLoad {
    UIButton *button = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeSystem];
    [self.view addSubview:button];
    [[button rac_signalForControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside] subscribe:self.buttonPressedSubject];
}

@end
```

Comment: Note: it would be better practice to expose `buttonPressedSubject` (source: [Framework Overview](https://github.com/ReactiveCocoa/ReactiveCocoa/blob/master/Documentation/FrameworkOverview.md)) as a `RACSignal`, but I didn't do so here in effort to simplify the example